# Creating a Pygame surface into another Pygame surface

Tags: python, pygame

I am trying to make a simple game which requires blocks and I have defined the coordinates of the blocks in a list which contain certain images and that of other blocks which contain other images.
So I was displaying all the images with respect to the main window created by

```
self.master_window = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height))
```

And I am creating the images form (0,0) of `self.master_window`.
But now I need to give some black space up and down of these image containing blocks, so I need to move the all the blocks 100 pixels down but I can't redefine all the coordinates (nor I can use some special methods like adding 100 to every y of the block in the list).
So I think if I could create a surface like `self.master_window` and place every thing in it in the same manner I was doing in the `self.master_window` and then place that surface in my desired coordinate in the main window.
So is there any way to do it because I have tried `pygame.Rect` as a surface but it doesn't seem to work.
Sorry for so less code in my post as i think its a basic question and it doesn't require that much code.
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have tried `pygame.Rect` as a surface:

You need to create a [`pygame.Surface`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html) object size of the world:

```py
self.draw_surface = pygame.display.Surface((w, h))
```

Draw all the objects on this surface and finally `blit` it on the mater window:

```py
self.master_window.blit(self.draw_surface, (offset_x, offset_y))
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, `pygame.display.set_mode` didn't work but if I replaced it with `pygame.Surface` then it worked perfectly fine.

Comment: @Aditya76 Yes of course. Sorry, copy/paste issue.